# Quotation marks in a complex formula including a variable

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this line of VBA code:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""283669 (2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _, Destination:=Range("$B$3")).QueryTable
```

I intend to use variable "Krs" declared by the user to be used in this line of code.

Code below does not seem to be working:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""&Krs&"";Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Range("$B$3")).QueryTable
```

neither the following:

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=""OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location="""&Krs&""";Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Range("$B$3")").QueryTable
```

I expect that my problems come from incorrect use of quotation mars, however I am unable to pinpoint where I make the mistake.

Comment: In your first example, this isthe listed Source:  `"OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location="` as those are between quotations.  take a second and note that a single quote, `"` will open/close, and where an actual quotation needs to occur in the string, you use double quotes, `""`  You are also flopping back and forth between semicolon and comma for arguments

Comment: Try `Source=$Workbook$;Location="" & Krs & ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""" & Krs & """;Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Range("$B$3")).QueryTable
```

Comment: This was it. I misunderstood how "," and ";" work as separators, as well as the placement of quotation marks. Thanks!